# Can i add acrylic clear coat over an epoxy paint for outdoor project

Tags: painting, paint, epoxy, varnishing

I used this [epoxy paint product from Rust-Oleum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082QNRJJD) (Amazon link) to paint our refrigerator and it worked well, at least for 3 years from now. But as the refrigerator is indoor I did not use any clear coat. But now I have some out-door chrome chairs that I want to paint using the same product, but as the chairs are outdoors and they are facing sun, rain and dust, I want to use a clear coat I found this [varnish product](https://www.vmditalia.com/en/prodotto/VMD-100).

Will these 2 products work together?

Comment: That epoxy paint is pretty good stuff - have you reason to believe that it will be harmed by the sun's UV?  Is the clear product you linked UV resistant?

Comment: @JPhi1618 the clear coat can provide a protection based on the seller at the shop

Comment: @jphi epoxy is vulnerable to UV.  Nature of the beast. Also if it didn't come in 2 parts you had to mix, it's not real epoxy doing the amine chains, so worst of both worlds - vulnerability without the durability.  That's the way it is with hardware store tier products.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want a clear coat? Do you want the hyper gloss and aesthetic depth that clearcoats give? Or do you just want a paint job that will last longer?

Certainly the UV of the sun will give any epoxy paint problems.  It will chalk and degrade from the UV.

You should not randomly over-top any paint with any other paint, unless the manufacturer specifically recommends the combination.  At the very least, stay within manufacturer line; however also consult documentation because even within lines, not everything plays well with everything.

Paint will not stick to chrome in any case.  You will need to aggressively scuff-sand it with 3M Scotchbrite (green) pads to remove all shininess or glossiness. That is a monumental chore, and I am surprised anyone would want to do all that.  But if you don't, it just won't work lol.

Honestly, I would buy other furniture.

If I were hellbound and determined to do it, I would gently beadblast as the most efficient way to remove all glossiness of the chrome, then have an automotive or marine shop apply a 2-part LPU topcoat such as *almost any automotive paint*, Interlux, Awlgrip etc. Try to arrange it so they paint it using the dregs left over from another job they are doing. 2-part paint becomes worthless a couple hours after it's mixed. White is the most popular yacht color, so it won't take long for them to finish a job with a little white left over.

Give the stuff 28 days to fully cure and it will be nearly indestructible.

Comment: i tried the epoxy paint product from Rust-Oleum on a chrome table and it worked just fine.. but this was an indoor table so i did not care much about clear coat.. so yes the product epoxy paint product from Rust-Oleum will adher well on chrome